# In SAS data interval calculation with intck by observationnumber returning missing values

Tags: sas

I am trying to find the interval in terms of weeks between two `$4.00` variables in date9 format.

The working example has two variable with dates formatted like 18JAN2017 and  25FEB2017. I want to create a third variable that shows the amount of weeks that fit into the interval between these dates within an observation/by subject ID.

I have tried:

```
  data test1;
  set inputs1;    
  difference = intck('week',input(date1,date9.),input(date2,date9.));
  run;
```

This code returns missing and $0 values. I expected a new variable named `difference` showing the amount of weeks between the two dates by observation.

Is this a matter of formatting or syntax, or is `intck` not able to deal with variables?

Comment: Please add sample values for `date1` and `date2` to make your example more reproducible.

Comment: Add the messages in the log to your question.  They should be informative as to the problem.

Comment: What do you mean by a `$4.00` variable?

Comment: When I view the variable content, both date variables are listed as numeric date9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A format tells SAS how to render a value when it is viewed.  The format does not change the underlying value.  So if variable `date1` is formatted `date9.` that means the variable is numeric, taking on values that represent date values in the SAS date epoch (0 is 01-JAN-1960).  As such, the numeric value should not be passed to `INPUT`.

A character variable can have a value whose construct is `ddMONyyyy`.  That variable would not be formatted `date9.`  The character value would be the formatted representation of a date value, and would have to be passed through `INPUT` to get the numeric value corresponding the date in SAS epoch.

`intck` most certainly can deal with variables -- in fact it deals with any expression that evaluates (implicitly or explicitly) to a number.  A string containing a formatted date representation cannot be implicitly evaluated to a SAS number, it would have to pass through `input`.

A formatted numeric passed through `INPUT` is just not correct.  The numeric value would go into the `INPUT` function implicitly unformatted and converted to a string and the 'digits' would be parsed according to the specified informat, and fail doing so.

Here is some sample code exploring the above narrative:

```
data _null_;

  today = today();
  tomorrow = today + 1;

  diff = intck ('day', today, tomorrow);

  put today tomorrow diff;

  date1num_as_char = '21560';
  date2num_as_char = '21561';

  diff = intck ('day', date1num_as_char, date2num_as_char);

  put date1num_as_char date2num_as_char diff;

  date1_as_string = '11JAN2019';  * not a SAS date value, is a date representation;
  date2_as_string = '12JAN2019';

  diff = intck ('day', date1_as_string, date2_as_string);

  put date1_as_string date2_as_string diff;

  now = today();
  format now date9.;

  put now=;

  now_through_input = input(now,date9.); * just wrong;
  put now_through_input=;
run;
```

Comment: When I do intck ('WEEK' , date1 ,date2);  I get the expected result. Thank!